# GPT root partition unable to grow; options?

Tags: lvm, gpt

I have the following partitions on my disk and lots of free space at the end of the disk.   I need to grow root partition to occupy most to the space(Some for Swap) without loosing partition content.  Given the GPT partition table, unable to grow root partition(sda5).   What are the options I have ?  is it possible to convert this to LVM or move other partition around etc.   Your help will really appreciated.

```
[root@abcd]# df -kh
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs         12G     0   12G   0% /dev
tmpfs            12G     0   12G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            12G  656K   12G   1% /run
tmpfs            12G     0   12G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda5       3.8G  2.2G  1.5G  60% /
/dev/sda6       966M  120K  900M   1% /tmp
/dev/sda7        22G  378M   20G   2% /var
/dev/sda4       6.7G   54M  6.3G   1% /opt
/dev/sda2       474M  141M  305M  32% /boot
/dev/sda1       2.0G  6.8M  2.0G   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           2.4G     0  2.4G   0% /run/user/1000

[root@abcd]# parted
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print                                                            
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 644GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  2098MB  2097MB  fat32           EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      2098MB  2622MB  524MB   ext4
 3      2622MB  11.0GB  8389MB  linux-swap(v1)                        swap
 4      11.0GB  18.4GB  7340MB  ext4
 5      18.4GB  22.5GB  4194MB  ext4
 6      22.5GB  23.6GB  1049MB  ext4
 7      23.6GB  47.2GB  23.6GB  ext4

(parted) p free                                                           
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 644GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                  Flags
        17.4kB  1049kB  1031kB  Free Space
 1      1049kB  2098MB  2097MB  fat32           EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      2098MB  2622MB  524MB   ext4
 3      2622MB  11.0GB  8389MB  linux-swap(v1)                        swap
 4      11.0GB  18.4GB  7340MB  ext4
 5      18.4GB  22.5GB  4194MB  ext4
 6      22.5GB  23.6GB  1049MB  ext4
 7      23.6GB  47.2GB  23.6GB  ext4
        47.2GB  644GB   597GB   Free Space

[root@abcd]# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0  600G  0 disk 
|--sda1   8:1    0    2G  0 part /boot/efi
|--sda2   8:2    0  500M  0 part /boot
|--sda3   8:3    0  7.8G  0 part [SWAP]
|--sda4   8:4    0  6.9G  0 part /opt
|--sda5   8:5    0  3.9G  0 part /
|--sda6   8:6    0 1000M  0 part /tmp
|--sda7   8:7    0   22G  0 part /var
sr0     11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: If you had set up the partitions using LVM this would be trivial. Failing that you will need to boot off of a rescue image and move the individual partitions around, to give sda5 more space to grow into. Example would be move sda7 to the end of the disk then move sda6 to immediately before sda7. Then you can grow the sda5 partition and resize the filesystem to match. It it not possible to convert the system to use LVM after the fact. The type of the partition table (gpt) does not play into this.

Comment: Thx for your suggestion.   Actually this virtual machine was an OVA deployment, so no option to select size and type of partition.   

I solved the issue for now by booting Ubuntu live CD and moved sda6 & 7 to the end and grown the root partition.